# Error: Corrupt grouped_df data using the old format when creating data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

After creating the [data.frame](/questions/tagged/data.frame) from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52169163/find-duplicate-rows-in-data-frame-based-on-multiple-columns-in-r) question, I access it with `df`, I see

> ```
> Error: Corrupt grouped_df data using the old format Run
> `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> ```

#### Example

Here is the exact code

```
df <- structure(list(orgid = c("USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", 
"USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", 
"USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ"), locid = c("USGS-01396030", 
"USGS-01396030", "USGS-01389850", "USGS-01389850", "USGS-01391500", 
"USGS-01391500", "USGS-01391500", "USGS-01391500", "USGS-01393960", 
"USGS-01390610", "USGS-01391500", "USGS-01390610", "USGS-01391500", 
"USGS-01378760", "USGS-01378760"), stdate = structure(c(11359, 
11359, 11359, 11359, 16504, 16504, 16112, 16112, 11367, 13860, 
12401, 13860, 16325, 13006, 13006), class = "Date"), sttime = structure(c(34200, 
34200, 36000, 36000, 40500, 40500, 39600, 39600, 36000, 39600, 
32400, 39600, 38400, 36900, 36900), class = c("hms", "difftime"
), units = "secs"), charnam = c("Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", 
"Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", 
"Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", 
"Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", 
"Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", 
"Specific conductance"), val = c(7450, 7300, 3210, 3180, 1930, 
1920, 1740, 1650, 1480, 1390, 1380, 1330, 1300, 1280, 1270), 
    valunit = c("uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", 
    "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", 
    "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", 
    "uS/cm @25C"), swqs = c("FW2-NT", "FW2-NT", "FW2-NT", "FW2-NT", 
    "FW2-NT", "FW2-NT", "FW2-NT", "FW2-NT", "FW2-NT", "FW2-NT", 
    "FW2-NT", "FW2-NT", "FW2-NT", "FW2-NT", "FW2-NT"), WMA = c(7L, 
    7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L), 
    year = c(2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2015L, 2015L, 2014L, 
    2014L, 2001L, 2007L, 2003L, 2007L, 2014L, 2005L, 2005L), 
    HUC14 = c("HUC02030104050090", "HUC02030104050090", "HUC02030103120050", 
    "HUC02030103120050", "HUC02030103140070", "HUC02030103140070", 
    "HUC02030103140070", "HUC02030103140070", "HUC02030104050010", 
    "HUC02030103140010", "HUC02030103140070", "HUC02030103140010", 
    "HUC02030103140070", "HUC02030103010040", "HUC02030103010040"
    )), .Names = c("orgid", "locid", "stdate", "sttime", "charnam", 
"val", "valunit", "swqs", "WMA", "year", "HUC14"), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = c("locid", 
"stdate", "sttime", "charnam", "valunit"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    13:14, 2:3, c(9L, 11L), 10L, 6:7, 12L, 4:5, 8L, 0:1), group_sizes = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), biggest_group_size = 2L, labels = structure(list(
    locid = c("USGS-01378760", "USGS-01389850", "USGS-01390610", 
    "USGS-01391500", "USGS-01391500", "USGS-01391500", "USGS-01391500", 
    "USGS-01393960", "USGS-01396030"), stdate = structure(c(13006, 
    11359, 13860, 12401, 16112, 16325, 16504, 11367, 11359), class = "Date"), 
    sttime = structure(c(36900, 36000, 39600, 32400, 39600, 38400, 
    40500, 36000, 34200), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), 
    charnam = c("Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", 
    "Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", 
    "Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", 
    "Specific conductance"), valunit = c("uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", 
    "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", 
    "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C")), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame", vars = c("locid", 
"stdate", "sttime", "charnam", "valunit"), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("locid", 
"stdate", "sttime", "charnam", "valunit")))
```

#### Question

How can I create/use the data.frame without any problems/errors?

Comment: Works fine for me without any error, gives a warning `Warning message:
Detecting old grouped_df format, replacing \`vars\` attribute by \`groups\``  which can be removed using `ungroup(df)`.

Comment: @RonakShah what happens when you run `df` after the assignment?

Comment: prints the dataframe with the above warning.

Comment: @RonakShah interesting. I do not see anything printed and I get the error. I'm running R 3.6.2 on macos. Wonder if you're on an older R version?

Comment: Yes, I am on `3.6.1`.

Comment: @RonakShah On another laptop, using R 3.6.3, I get your error message. Strange